# How do I make the div I'm appending to my html with jQuery show up on my page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok. I'm trying to get jQuery to insert a div into my html, but it won't or, at least, I can't see it having any effect.

**The jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ml1").click(function(){
        $("#container").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
    });
});
```

**The html:**

```
<body>
      <div id="container">
            <header>
                Header
            </header>
            <div id="left" class="panel">
                <div id="main">
                    <ul>
                        <li id= "ml1"><a href="#">%</a></li>
                        <li id= "ml2"><a href="#">%</a></li>
                        <li id= "ml3"><a href="#">%</a></li>
```

I know that none of the html closes. I'm just giving a small chunk for reference. Note: I've also given #overlay some dimension and colour in my CSS file, so it should show up on the page.

When I insert t `<div id='overlay'></div>` straight into my html, under #container, it has an effect, but I can't get it to do anything with the jQuery. I have tried applying the click to the "a href" element as well.

My ultimate goal is to create an overlay div that appears whenever an item in the list is clicked, but at the moment I'm just trying to get the new div to appear. If anyone wants to give me advice for the longer term regarding that goal, please feel free.

Comment: Checked the console for errors? Is your jQuery within a document ready call or at the end of your document? Also, multiple clicks on ml1 will append multiple divs with the same ID which is a no-no.

Comment: Your code is working - see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6Qyf/)

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. I think you have not noticed the change. To see the change, just have some text between overlay div

Comment: Are you loading jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: As you have not noticed that your code was already working, but just to give you clear picture on your query, I am sharing this code with fiddle link:

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2vby/

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="container">
    <header>Header</header>
    <div id="left" class="panel">
        <div id="main">
            <ul>
                <li id="ml1"><a href="#">ml1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="ml2"><a href="#">ml2</a>
                </li>
                <li id="ml3"><a href="#">ml3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#overlay {
    background:#dadada;
    opacity:0.8;
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
```

JS CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ml1").click(function () {
        $("#container").after("<div id='overlay'></div>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all (great to see the unforeseen issues people pick up in code as well). Not loading jQuery was the issue (n00b error, I'm afraid). I was linked to the wrong library.

RealDeepak: Thanks for your answer. I notice you replaced ".append" with ".after". If you could elaborate on your reasons for that change, I'd be grateful.